# ASP.NET MVC - How to save some data between requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to solve the problem: when a user is being logged into a WebSite (via user control .ascx stored on the Master Page), it's name is being stored in a Page.User.Identity.Name property. OK, but how to retrieve that user name in the controller ? Is it possible without registering  System.Security.Principal namespace in the controller ? In the other words - the controller must know whose user wants to do some action (e.g. change account data). I could store it's name in the Html.Hidden control on each View but I don't want to have a mess in my Views

Comment: Are you mixing MVC and WebForms?

Comment: No, I don't. I just want to have access to the User name anytime I need. I don't use Membership class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IPrincipal User` is one of the members in your controller (it is a property), so all you have to do to get the name of the currently logged in user in your controller method is

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer is correct. Another alternative is to use the `Thread` class:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Session to store user-related data?

Comment: One of the benefits of ASP.NET MVC is that it eliminates the need to encode large amounts of Session data in the web page.

Comment: @Robert - 'encode large amounts of Session data in the web page'. Unsure what you mean here. I was referring to the Session in memory in IIS. Sounds like you're referring to webforms ViewState? I'm confused by your comment. :)

Comment: Mmm, think you're right. Got my terminology confused.  That said, I have yet to use Session in an ASP.NET MVC app, given the ability to use ViewModel classes, ViewData and data binding to do the same thing.